# Set desktop background image with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to set the desktop background image using JavaScript? I'm pretty sure it's not possible but I thought I would check.

If it isn't possible, is there any way for it to be done from the page?

Comment: :o you have 666 rep ... wicked ... +1 to save you ;)

Comment: nnnnnoooooooooooooo ... damn.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If that was possible, it would be a serious security issue. Many browser allow the user to right-click an image and select "use as wallpaper" or something similar.

Comment: I also search for this but didn't get any solution. Is there not a single library of javascript or jquery which do this. Or have any alternative to do this by php???

Answer (score 6):

No, this is not possible (without a browser plugin).

You should just write instructions to the user for how to set an image as their wallpaper.

Answer (score 1):

I certainly hope not.

Changing the OS's desktop background requires access to the filesystem. JS doesn't have this, but browser plugins (Java applets, Flash, etc) do, so that's where you'd need to look.